# android sending multiple messages to multiple numbers is not working

Tags: android, sms

I want to send multiple messages to multiple numbers(like sending seat numbers to the persons who reserved the seat in a theatre)as part of my project.Here i have retrieved messages and phone numbers from database successfully,and displayed them in a listview,this is my code.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE date='"+label+"'", null);

        userId.clear();
        user_phoneNumber.clear();

        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                userId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID)));
                user_phoneNumber.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONENUMBER)));


    } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        DisplayAdapter disadpt = new DisplayAdapter(home.this,userId, user_phoneNumber);
        lv.setAdapter(disadpt);
        disadpt.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mCursor.close();
```

Here when i run the program it is sending only to the first number i mentioned there, and all messages is going to that number.But i want send first message to first number and second message to the second number like that...can any one help me please to find the cod.

```
  String receipentsMessage[] = {userId.toString()};


    //this id is used as their seat number
        String receipentsNumber[] = {user_phoneNumber.toString()};

        for (int i = 0; i < receipentsNumber.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < receipentsMessage.length; j++)
        {

        try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(receipentsNumber[i], null,receipentsMessage[j], null,
                            null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent to" + " " + receipentsNumber[i]+receipentsMessage[j], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `receipentsMessage[j]` instead of `receipentsMessage[i]`?

Comment: Sorry still all the messages is going only to the first number,and others not getting any messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see your code:

```
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(receipentsNumber[i], null,receipentsMessage[i], null,
                    null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent to" + " " + receipentsNumber[i]+receipentsMessage[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Problem is that you are not using your `j` index. Suggested code:

```
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(receipentsNumber[i], null,receipentsMessage[j], null,
                    null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent to" + " " + receipentsNumber[i]+receipentsMessage[j], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

EDIT

```
    for (int i = 0; i < user_phoneNumber.size(); i++)

    {

    try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(user_phoneNumber.get(i), null,userId.get(i), null,
                        null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent to" + " " + user_phoneNumber.get(i)+userId.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry i have corrected that error but still all the messages is going only to the first number,and others not getting any messages

Comment: You have this variable: user_phoneNumber. Can you show its declaration? If its class overrides the toString method, can you show your toString method as well?

Comment: actually it is stored in database,and i fetched them into list view using cursor adapter. private ArrayList<String> user_phoneNumber = new ArrayList<String>();,private ArrayList<String> user_message = new ArrayList<String>();.

Comment: Then you do not need to convert it to an array, you can iterate it with for (int i = 0; i < user_phoneNumber.size(); i++) and you can refer to an element with user_phoneNumber.get(i)

Comment: Iam beginner to programming,can u modify with my codes,and put them as an answer.

Comment: Hai ,your code was helped  me  to save my time,but it had little bit error again like sending all messages again to a number two times,but now i got an idea ,and editted your codes little bit.now its working  perfectly.thankyou so much sir

Comment: In my edit I have converted the for loops into iterating the ArrayList objects. Sorry for leaving the two loops there, I thought this is what you wanted, but anyways, I am glad that things are resolved now. Cheers.